# PHP - Back end web service method to open url on server

Tags: php, url, curl, cron

I have the following scenario:

1) The user fills in some details on a user form and clicks on the submit button.
2) submit button click sends a AJAX request to the back end server.
3) Server does some processing at its end and....

**Issue:**
4) After some processing, I need the server to open a url on the server.
e.g. on command line: start http://domain.com/main.swf

I need a php code - either a cron job or a function that can trigger the page (swf file) to run on the server.

Note: I need to run swf file on server due to some very specific project requirements.

I am trying something like:

```
exec('start url');
```

But, this is not working for me. Please suggest what I may be doing wrong or how can I achieve this. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: As an alternative, I also tried to create .bat file and was trying to execute that. Can someone guide me on way to execute a bat file

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this will help You**

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

- you can call external url by  `cURL Functions`
- You can use another function too `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Thanks Dinesh. Can you please help me on this: Actually I need to run a swf file on server. Not sure but it is not running for me.

Comment: My user scenario is to have a ajax call from user form to a web service api that triggers this swf page on server and then user is redirected to a separate page.